# How to start two instances of a process through fork without modifying the program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I am trying to fork a process from another at the start. For this I tried to modify the `__libc_start_main` function in glibc (a modified glibc that I use) and tried to put the fork there, but could not compile the glibc as it gives an error whenever I try to do that. What are other options and why inserting fork in `__libc_start_main` doesn't work?

Again notice that I want to do it in a way that no program modification is required, that is modification in glibc is OK but not the program.

In `__libc_start_main`, I try to fork like this.

```
if (__builtin_expect (! not_first_call, 1))
    {
      struct pthread *self;
      fork(); // <-- here

      self = THREAD_SELF;

      /* Store old info.  */
      unwind_buf.priv.data.prev = THREAD_GETMEM (self, cleanup_jmp_buf);
      unwind_buf.priv.data.cleanup = THREAD_GETMEM (self, cleanup);

      /* Store the new cleanup handler info.  */
      THREAD_SETMEM (self, cleanup_jmp_buf, &unwind_buf);

      /* Run the program.  */
      result = main (argc, argv, __environ MAIN_AUXVEC_PARAM);
    }
```

The error i get is the following.

```
file '/build/sunrpc/xbootparam_prot.T' already exists and may be overwritten
make[2]: *** [build/sunrpc/xbootparam_prot.stmp] Error 1
```

Comment: what error are you getting when compiling your modified libc ?

Comment: Why don't you just create a wrapper program, rename the old one to something else, and in the wrapper program fork and exec, then just exec the renamed process?

Comment: If you don't have any static data, you could `fork()` first thing in `main()`. You'd have to think about file descriptors and signal handlers and all that of course.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Why can't you just `fork()` at the start of `main`?

Comment: Adam: I dont want to modify the program. I need to make this work for any program, so as to make it transparent.

Comment: But why are you trying to do that?  What possible use could there be for having two identical copies of every program you run?

Comment: Have you tried building unpatched glibc? You may want to download your distro's source package, and see exactly how they configure it (etc.).

Comment: The C library is heavily dependent on the kernel, so usually it's shipped tightly coupled to your distribution. Rebuilding a C library from scratch should certainly involve a lot of configuration.

Comment: Arbitrary programs won't run successfully when always forked. Some programs are using or implementing some locking machinery and really want to be unique....

Answer (score 1):

If you're statically linking to an unmodifiable object with the main entry point, you could use symbol wrapping to sneak the fork() before the object's main().

For example, main.o that can't be modified:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   printf( "In main()\n" );
   return 0;
}
```

Your wrapper symbol within glibc:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int __wrap_main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   printf( "In wrapper\n" );
   if ( fork() ) {
      return __real_main( argc, argv );
   } else {
      printf( "Other process did something else\n" );
      return 0;
   }
}
```

And use the --wrap command linker command:

```
gcc -o app main.o wrap.o -Wl,--wrap=main

$ ./app 
In wrapper
In main()
$ Other process did something else
```